# Top bar overlapping on the slider below it

Tags: html, wordpress, css, html5-canvas

If you visit [this page](http://www.morrisonsmarketingsolutions.com/) (Wordpress site) on your mobile phone (landscape view), then you will see that the top bar containing the menu and the logo is overlapping over the slider below it. It's not happening on the desktop view and mobile portrait view, then how come on the mobile landscape view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
.transparent:not(.photo-scroller-album) .masthead:not(.side-header):not(.mixed-header) {
  position: relative !important;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much that worked out perfectly. I pasted that code in custom css in the WP admin.

Answer (score 2):

```
.transparent:not(.photo-scroller-album):not(.phantom-sticky) .masthead:not(.side-header):not(.mixed-header), .transparent .mixed-header.side-header-h-stroke {
  position: absolute;width: 100%;z-index: 101;
}
```

this code is came from your `@media screen and (min-width: 400px)` media query

Answer (score 1):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) and (min-width: 400px) {
  .transparent:not(.photo-scroller-album) .masthead:not(.side-header):not(.mixed-header) {
  position: absolute;width: 100%;z-index: 101;
  }
  and
  .transparent:not(.photo-scroller-album):not(.phantom-sticky) .masthead:not(.side-header):not(.mixed-header), .transparent .mixed-header.side-header-h-stroke {
  position: absolute;width: 100%;z-index: 101;
  }
}
```

remove this css code from your media query

Comment: Hi, thanks but can you please tell me where this code is, i couldn't find it in main.css of the theme.

Comment: Okay so I have searched every single file in the theme and the child theme and I couldn't find the code you have mentioned. Could you please tell me?

Answer (score 0):

code is in the **media-82b7009747.css?ver=1.0.0** file. if you can't find it add css in your custom file in media query and change css from absolute to relative